# Gutenberg Block Get Author Details

Tags: block-editor

How do I pass author details such as name, bio and avatar to a block?

Comment: Is this for saving or display? I'd keep in mind that you could get what you asked for but have the problem that changing the author doesn't update the block if you're not careful

Comment: For display I would rather the block only get this information rather than have a user pick it that way it's controlled from wp itself.

So if i create the block it gets the name and bio of the post author of the post but if I change it from the post edit screen it updates to the new author if that makes sense.

Comment: doing that will have major problems with blocks showing out of date information or incorrect information if done via JS in the editor UI

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass author details such as name, bio and avatar to a block?

**You don't.**

This would break quick edit/site editor/block themes/synced patterns/etc, and cause a lot of problems. **A block that relies on post author information or any other dynamic post value must be a PHP server rendered block.**

This is because we don't know the correct value until the moment we render it, and the answer changes depending on where the block is being displayed/edited.

Doing it in javascript is a mistake and will cause problems with both out of date authors, and broken blocks.

Use `register_block_type` to register the block in PHP, and specify a PHP function to render the blocks output using the `render_callback` option and use ***standard author PHP functions such as `the_author` etc..*** You can also use PHP filters to swap out the author at runtime so that it's always the post author.

Then, in the blocks JS implementation, return `null` in the save method. You can retrieve the current author from the WP Core data store for previewing purposes when inside the block editor, but it isn't necessary for it to work on the frontend

***So you would never need or want to find out the current author in the javascript of your block.***

### Why You Can't Use Core Data in the edit component.

> Ok so how do I call the current author using core/data ?

You don't, that would break your block especially if you tried to use it for a save component. Render it in PHP, since we don't know what the value should be until the block is shown on the frontend.

For example, lets say that we displayed it inside the edit component using core data. Now all Query loop blocks will incorrectly show the same author regardless of which post.

If you did it in the site editor or template editor, then your block would show the author of the template, not the post.

Comment: Ok so how do I call the current author using core/data ?

Comment: Eh I'm not sure how to do that off the top of my head, but it shouldn't be needed to get it functional on the frontend

Comment: @Astrid Came across this question while working on something similiar and for anyone else who finds this, you can get current author via `wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostAttribute('author');`

Comment: wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostAttribute('author') => undefined for me 6.2.2

Comment: note that those snippets will not work if the block is in the site editor, inside a query loop block, if the author is changed using quick edit, if the block is inside a reusable block/synced pattern, or in a theme template

Comment: Looking back on this, if you're implementing a block that's rendered server side, you would never need to use core/data, you'd use the same functions as a classic theme in your blocks render function, aka `the_author();`, you'd never want or need to get that data in the javascript! Your blocks edit control would have a server render component that pulls the data from the server

Comment: I've made edits to improve the answer, and explain why the coments about getting the post author are incorrect and lead to bugs